# How to set datetimepicker() current time?

Tags: php, jquery, datetimepicker

i notice when i set datetime in text box fields

```
<input type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s')?>" />
```

`datetimepicker()` will set to current datetime but now i want the text box value is **empty** , but `datetimepicker()` still can show to user current date time when pop up.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MGQDf/2/)

Comment: Remove `<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s')?>` then. No?

Comment: if i remove , only date is set to today but not time .. http://jsfiddle.net/MGQDf/2/

Comment: @rusly : There is a button "now" in datepicker click that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an addon for jQuery UI DateTimePicker: [Plugin Page](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

After installing this addon, you can put time manually or automatically:

```
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    hour: 13,
    minute: 15
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s')?>` from `value` attribute. So Text box will be empty when user see it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the php date function in your html input controllike this

```
<input type="text" id="date" value="" />
$(function () {
$("#datepicker").datetimepicker();
});
```